# Double pointer C/C++

Tags: c, pointers

can someone explain to me how double pointers work? On this code for example, why it prints the values that it prints in the end?

```
int main(void) {
    int anArray[] = {5,16,33,99};
    int * p = anArray;

    printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
    p++;
    printf("Now *p = %d\n", *p);

    int * q = &anArray[3];
    int ** x = &q;
    **x = 12;
    *x = p;
    **x = 42;
    q[1] = 9;

    for (int i =0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("anArray[%d] = %d\n",i, anArray[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Draw it out; some people understand diagrams better.

Comment: "Double pointer" is just a pointer to a pointer. Carefully go through each `&` and `*` and see what the result/type is and what it refers to.

Comment: A pointer `T*` points at an object of type `T`. You can use it to manipulate the object that it points at. If `T` happens to be a pointer, then `T*` is a pointer to a pointer. But there's no magic there. You use that `T*` to manipulate the object that it points at.

Comment: Your question is about a pointer to pointer.  A double pointer is a pointer that can hold the address of a double.  `int **p` declares a pointer to pointer.  `double *p` declares a double pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's fully draw it out:

```c
int anArray[] = {5,16,33,99};  // 4 values in consecutive addresses

//            ----
// anArray ->   5
//            ----
//             16
//            ----
//             33
//            ----
//             99
//            ----

int * p = anArray; // A new variable, whose contents points to the address of anArray

//            ---------
// anArray ->   5       <-+
//            ---------   |
//             16         |
//            ---------   |
//             33         |
//            ---------   |
//             99         |
//            ---------   |
//       p ->  anArray   -+
//            ---------

printf("*p = %d\n", *p);  // prints 5
p++;                      // increment pointer p to the next element.

//            -----------
// anArray ->   5      
//            -----------
//             16         <-+
//            -----------   |
//             33           |
//            -----------   |
//             99           |
//            -----------   |
//       p ->  anArray+1   -+
//            ---------

printf("Now *p = %d\n", *p); // prints 16
int * q = &anArray[3];       // new pointer variable, points to 4th element of anArray (0-based)

//            -----------
// anArray ->   5      
//            -----------
//             16         <-+
//            -----------   |
//             33           |
//            -----------   |
//             99           | <-+
//            -----------   |   |
//       p ->  anArray+1   -+   |
//            -----------       |
//       q ->  anArray+3   -----+
//            -----------

int ** x = &q;  // new pointer variable, points to address of q pointer variable

//            -----------
// anArray ->   5      
//            -----------
//             16         <-+
//            -----------   |
//             33           |
//            -----------   |
//             99           | <-+
//            -----------   |   |
//       p ->  anArray+1   -+   |
//            -----------       |
//       q ->  anArray+3   -----+ <-+
//            -----------           |
//       x ->  q           ---------+
//            -----------

**x = 12;  // get address in x (q), then address in q (anArray+3) and write 12 to it

//            -----------
// anArray ->   5      
//            -----------
//             16         <-+
//            -----------   |
//             33           |
//            -----------   |
//             12           | <-+
//            -----------   |   |
//       p ->  anArray+1   -+   |
//            -----------       |
//       q ->  anArray+3   -----+ <-+
//            -----------           |
//       x ->  q           ---------+
//            -----------

*x = p;  // get address in x (q) and write p value to it (anArray+1)

//            -----------
// anArray ->   5      
//            -----------
//             16         <-+ <-+
//            -----------   |   |
//             33           |   |
//            -----------   |   |
//             12           |   |
//            -----------   |   |
//       p ->  anArray+1   -+   |
//            -----------       |
//       q ->  anArray+1   -----+ <-+
//            -----------           |
//       x ->  q           ---------+
//            -----------

**x = 42;  // get address in x (q), then address in q (anArray+1) and write a 42 to it

//            -----------
// anArray ->   5
//            -----------
//             42         <-+ <-+
//            -----------   |   |
//             33           |   |
//            -----------   |   |
//             12           |   |
//            -----------   |   |
//       p ->  anArray+1   -+   |
//            -----------       |
//       q ->  anArray+1   -----+ <-+
//            -----------           |
//       x ->  q           ---------+
//            -----------

q[1] = 9;  // get address in q (anArray+1) add one element (anArray+2), and assign 9

//            -----------
// anArray ->   5      
//            -----------
//             42         <-+ <-+   (q[0])
//            -----------   |   |
//              9           |   |   (q[1])
//            -----------   |   |
//             12           |   |
//            -----------   |   |
//       p ->  anArray+1   -+   |
//            -----------       |
//       q ->  anArray+1   -----+ <-+
//            -----------           |
//       x ->  q           ---------+
//            -----------
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's draw out:

```
int q = 15;
int * p = &q;
int * * z = &p;

            q   
          +----+  
    p --> | 15 |  
    ^     +----+  
    |  
    z
```

In the above drawing, `q` is an integer variable with the value 15.
The *pointer* `p` points to the variable `q`.
The *pointer* `z` points to the pointer `p`.

The expression `*z` refers to the value in the pointer `p`.
The expression `**z` or rewritten as `*(*z)` refers to the variable `q` (following the links).

We know that `(*z)` is the pointer `p`, so let's replace:
`*(*z) == *(p);`

We can replace `*(p)` with `q`, from the above definitions:  `*(*z) == *(p) == q;`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I will use a simple example to demonstrate double pointers:

```
int x = 5; // Simply 5
int* y = &x; // y holds the address of x
int** z = &y; // z holds the address of y
```

When `y` holds the address of `x` it means that no matter what is the value of `x`, `y` still points to it (`points` means 'holding the address of').
So, changing `x` also changes `*y` which is the syntax for accessing the value that `y` points to.
The same is applied to `z`, but here we need to use `*` operator twice in order to access `x` value, because `z` points to `y` which points to `x` (meaning `**z` == `*y` == `x`).

To understand your question we also need to understand what arrays are in `C`.
Array is a sequence of elements (e.g. integers, chars and etc...) in a contiguous memory location.
An array is actually a pointer meaning if we have `int anArray[] = {5,16,33,99};` accessing `anArray` using `anArray[0]` is the same as `*anArray`, or `anArray[1]` is the same as `*(anArray+sizeof(int))` and etc...

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a variable holding a memory address which contains the value you want. For example:

```
int value = 42;
int* value_ptr = &value;
int access_via_ptr = *value_ptr;
```

A double pointer, or a pointer to pointer, is a variable holding an address of another pointer, which holds an address to the value you want. For example:

```
int value = 42;
int* value_ptr = &value;
int** value_ptr = &value_ptr;
int access_via_ptr_ptr = **value_ptr;
```

Why would you want to use **? One really useful way is in functions. You want to pass a pointer to a pointer, so that the function can setup the pointer address for you. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

void GetPtr(int** val_ptr_ptr, int init_contents)
{
    // val_ptr_ptr should point to a pointer
    // lets allocate it
    *val_ptr_ptr = new int;

    // de-reference ptr->ptr->val to initialize
    // the contents
    **val_ptr_ptr = init_contents;
}

int main(void)
{
    int* val_ptr = NULL;
    GetPtr(&val_ptr, 42);
    std::cout << *val_ptr;
    delete val_ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

In this example we want a function to allocate memory. We want that memory to be stored in a pointer outside the function, so we can access it. We pass in an address of outside pointer, or a pointer to a pointer. We then assign the address inside the function.